# JSON with backslashes (PHP)

Tags: php, json

I have an issue. I want to get the values of **status**, **response_code** and **level** inside **message**, but I'm unable to do it with this format, any suggestions?

```
{"data":{"signUpUser":null},"errors":[{"message":"[{\"registration\":{\"status\":\"failed\",\"response_code\":\"0\",\"level\":\"U\"}}]","locations":[{"line":2,"column":3}],"path":["signUpUser"]}]}
```

Formatted:

```
{
   "data":{
      "signUpUser":null
   },
   "errors":[
      {
         "message":"[{\"registration\":{\"status\":\"failed\",\"response_code\":\"0\",\"level\":\"U\"}}]",
         "locations":[
            {
               "line":2,
               "column":3
            }
         ],
         "path":[
            "signUpUser"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need do json_encode twice, first for whole data, second for message string:

```
<?php
$json_string = '{"data":{"signUpUser":null},"errors":[{"message":"[{\"registration\":{\"status\":\"failed\",\"response_code\":\"0\",\"level\":\"U\"}}]","locations":[{"line":2,"column":3}],"path":["signUpUser"]}]}';

$json = json_decode($json_string);

$err_message = $json->errors[0]->message;

$err_json = json_decode($err_message);

print_r($err_json);
```

[Here you can try the code](https://phpize.online/?phpses=9f30dea104da25b76582baf77bfad66f&sqlses=null&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80)

Comment: Thank you so much, that's the best response!

Answer (score 0):

The "message" is a stringified version of a json object. You will need to `json_decode(message)` before you can inspect it.

Answer (score 0):

You need use json_decode

```
$res = json_decode($json);
print_r($res);
```